# Does multiplying by the pseudoinverse preserve an inequality?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, pseudoinverse

Does the pseudoinverse of any full rank matrix preserve an inequality? In other words, if $Ax\geq b$, does $x \geq A^\dagger b$ hold?

Here, $A^\dagger$ is the pseudoinverse of a full rank matrix $A$.

Comment: *Hint:* If $A=-I$, then its pseudo inverse is $-I$.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Thank you :) Got my answer.